# Setting certain response headers only if Referer is invalid

Tags: http, clickjacking, iframe

I came across this technique and I'm curious if there are any flaws in this design. A site sets the `X-Frame-Options` response header to deny only if the `Referer` header is not define or does not match the site's domain. When the `Referer` header is set to the correct domain, the `X-Frame-Options` is not defined in the response.

Is there a flaw in this? I feel like depending on the `Referer` header is not enough here to prevent clickjacking but can't think of a real-world use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any headers provided by the client can be spoofed. Using cURL, I can craft an HTTP request to contain any headers I want. Depending on the referrer is clever, but clever is not good enough. If I'm crafting the request as an iFrame, I have full control over the request header.

Here's a use case, courtesy of the brilliant minds at Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432821/is-it-possible-to-add-request-headers-to-an-iframe-src-request

Evil Website --> AJAX script to preload headers -> Your site.

Add x-frame-options on every page in every case, and use framebusting scripts for older browsers.